# Django Relations with Scrapy how are items saved?

Tags: python, django, scrapy, scrapy-pipeline

I just need to understand How can I detect whether scrapy saved and item in spider ? I'm fetching items from a site and after that I'm fetching comments on that item. So first I have to save the item after that I'll save comments. But when I'm writing code after yield it's giving me this error.

`save() prohibited to prevent data loss due to unsaved related object ''.`

And this is my code

```
def parseProductComments(self, response):

        name = response.css('h1.product-name::text').extract_first()
        price = response.css('span[id=offering-price] > span::text').extract_first()
        node = response.xpath("//script[contains(text(),'var utagData = ')]/text()")
        data = node.re('= (\{.+\})')[0]  #data = xpath.re(" = (\{.+\})")
        data = json.loads(data)

        barcode = data['product_barcode']

        objectImages = []
        for imageThumDiv in response.css('div[id=productThumbnailsCarousel]'):
            images = imageThumDiv.xpath('img/@data-src').extract()
            for image in images:
                imageQuality = image.replace('/80/', '/500/')
                objectImages.append(imageQuality)
        company = Company.objects.get(pk=3)
        comments = []
        item = ProductItem(name=name, price=price, barcode=barcode, file_urls=objectImages, product_url=response.url,product_company=company, comments = comments)
        yield item
        print item["pk"]
        for commentUl in response.css('ul.chevron-list-container'):

            url = commentUl.css('span.link-more-results::attr(href)').extract_first()
            if url is not None:
                for commentLi in commentUl.css('li.review-item'):
                    comment = commentLi.css('p::text').extract_first()
                    commentItem = CommentItem(comment=comment, product=item.instance)

                    yield commentItem
            else:

                yield scrapy.Request(response.urljoin(url), callback=self.parseCommentsPages, meta={'item': item.instance})
```

And this is my pipeline.

```
def comment_to_model(item):
    model_class = getattr(item, 'Comment')
    if not model_class:
        raise TypeError("Item is not a `DjangoItem` or is misconfigured")

def get_comment_or_create(model):
    model_class = type(model)
    created = False
    # Normally, we would use `get_or_create`. However, `get_or_create` would
    # match all properties of an object (i.e. create a new object
    # anytime it changed) rather than update an existing object.
    #
    # Instead, we do the two steps separately
    try:
        # We have no unique identifier at the moment; use the name for now.
        obj = model_class.objects.get(product=model.product, comment=model.comment)
    except model_class.DoesNotExist:
        created = True
        obj = model  # DjangoItem created a model for us.
        obj.save()

    return (obj, created)

def get_or_create(model):
    model_class = type(model)
    created = False
    # Normally, we would use `get_or_create`. However, `get_or_create` would
    # match all properties of an object (i.e. create a new object
    # anytime it changed) rather than update an existing object.
    #
    # Instead, we do the two steps separately
    try:
        # We have no unique identifier at the moment; use the name for now.
        obj = model_class.objects.get(product_company=model.product_company, barcode=model.barcode)
    except model_class.DoesNotExist:
        created = True
        obj = model  # DjangoItem created a model for us.
        obj.save()

    return (obj, created)


def update_model(destination, source, commit=True):
    pk = destination.pk

    source_dict = model_to_dict(source)
    for (key, value) in source_dict.items():
        setattr(destination, key, value)

    setattr(destination, 'pk', pk)

    if commit:
        destination.save()
    return destination


class ProductItemPipeline(object):
    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        if isinstance(item, ProductItem):
            item['cover_photo'] = item['files'][0]['path']
            item_model = item.instance
            model, created = get_or_create(item_model)
            #update_model(model, item_model)

            if created:
                for image in item['files']:
                    imageItem = ProductImageItem(image=image['path'], product=item.instance)
                    imageItem.save()
                # for comment in item['comments']:
                #     commentItem = CommentItem(comment=comment, product= item.instance)
                #     commentItem.save()
            return item
        if isinstance(item, CommentItem):
            comment_to_model = item.instance
            model, created = get_comment_or_create(comment_to_model)
            if created:
                print model
            else:
                print created
            return item
```

Comment: 1. Could you please show object what you are trying to save?       
2. I am sorry, but your code looks bad: `get_or_create` is the same as `get_comment_or_create` and them duplicate default django `get_or_create` method, method `comment_to_model` is unreadable. I suggest format your code to make logic more readable.

Answer (score 2):

### Get or Create

A large part of your code seems to deal with an apparent weakness of get_or_create

```
# Normally, we would use `get_or_create`. However, `get_or_create` would
# match all properties of an object (i.e. create a new object
# anytime it changed) rather than update an existing object.
```

Fortunately this apparent short coming can be easily overcome. Thanks to the default parameter of [get_or_create](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/#get-or-create)

> Any keyword arguments passed to get_or_create() — except an optional
>   one called defaults — will be used in a get() call. If an object is
>   found, get_or_create() returns a tuple of that object and False. If
>   multiple objects are found, get_or_create raises
>   MultipleObjectsReturned. If an object is not found, get_or_create()
>   will instantiate and save a new object, returning a tuple of the new
>   object and True.

### Update or Create

Still not convinced that get_or_create is the right man for the job? I am not either. There is something even better. [update_or_create](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/#update-or-create)!!

> A convenience method for updating an object with the given kwargs,
>   creating a new one if necessary. The defaults is a dictionary of
>   (field, value) pairs used to update the object.

But I am not going to dwell on the user of update_or_create because lines in your code that attempt to update your model have been commented out and you have not clearly state what you want to update.

### The new pipeline

Using the standard API methods, your module that contains your pipeline just reduces to the  ProductItemPipeline class. And that can be modified

```
class ProductItemPipeline(object):
    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        if isinstance(item, ProductItem):
            item['cover_photo'] = item['files'][0]['path']

            model, created = ProductItem.get_or_create(product_company=item['product_company'], barcode=item['bar_code'], 
    defaults={'Other_field1': value1, 'Other_field2': value2})

            if created:
                for image in item['files']:
                    imageItem = ProductImageItem(image=image['path'], product=item.instance)
                    imageItem.save()
            return item

        if isinstance(item, CommentItem):

            model, created = CommentItem.get_or_create(field1=value1, defaults={ other fields go in here'})

            if created:
                print model
            else:
                print created
            return item
```

### Bug in the original code

I do believe this to be the place where the bug existed.

```
  obj = model_class.objects.get(product=model.product, comment=model.comment)
```

Now we are not using that so the bug should disappear. If you still have problems please paste the *full traceback*.